# Flutter - Custom invoice widget

Tags: flutter, mobile

i want to create widget like this cant everyone help me to create widget invoice,
because I'm still a beginner and still need help to learn, maybe i have tried to use container but always failed
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0DH2.png)

Your suggestions are appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to create that Widget is to have the invoice shape as an image and place behind the text content with a Stack, maybe something like this:
Result:

[image]

**Widget:**

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 450,
          width: 450,
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Image.asset(
                'assets/images/invoice_background.png',
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 24.0),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    const Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              "Invoice",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                            Text(
                              "Mr John Dow",
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        CircleAvatar(
                          maxRadius: 30,
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 26),
                    const MySeparator(color: Colors.grey),
                    const SizedBox(height: 24),
                    const Text(
                      "Title of the Invoice",
                      style:
                          TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                        height: 200,
                        child: ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: 5,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                              child: Text(
                                "Detail ${index + 1}",
                                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                        ))
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

**The dashed line:**

```
class MySeparator extends StatelessWidget {
  const MySeparator({Key? key, this.height = 1, this.color = Colors.black})
      : super(key: key);
  final double height;
  final Color color;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
        final boxWidth = constraints.constrainWidth();
        const dashWidth = 10.0;
        final dashHeight = height;
        final dashCount = (boxWidth / (2 * dashWidth)).floor();
        return Flex(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          direction: Axis.horizontal,
          children: List.generate(dashCount, (_) {
            return SizedBox(
              width: dashWidth,
              height: dashHeight,
              child: DecoratedBox(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(color: color),
              ),
            );
          }),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You can also use `Container` put the `image` in `DecorationImage` and all the text will be in the `child`, Than you can eliminate the `Stack`.